# What is the Gauss sum equivalent of $\Gamma(s+1) = s\Gamma(s)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gamma-function, gauss-sums

Gauss sums are analogous to the Gamma function: fix a complex number $s$ with real part $>0$. Then we have a multiplicative character $\chi_s :\mathbf R^{\times}_{>0} \to \mathbf C^\times$ given by $x \mapsto x^s$. We also have an additive character $\lambda: \mathbf R \to \mathbf C^\times$ given by $x \mapsto e^{-x}$. The inner product of these two characters over $\mathbf R^{\times}_{>0}$,

$$\langle \chi_s, \lambda \rangle : = \int_0^\infty x^s e^{-x} \frac{dx}{x}$$

is the Gamma function. (Remark that $dx/x$ is the Haar measure on $\mathbf R^{\times}_{>0}$.)

For Gauss sums, say over the finite field $\mathbf F_p$, we take the inner product of a Dirichlet character $\chi : \mathbf F_p^\times \to \mathbf C^\times$ with the additive character $\lambda : \mathbf F_p \to \mathbf C^\times$ given by $x \mapsto e^{2\pi i x/p}$:

$$\eta(\chi) = \sum_{x \in \mathbf F_p^\times} \chi(x) \lambda(x).$$

With this notation, the Gamma function 'is' $\eta(\chi_s)$.

There are many analogies between Gauss sums and the Gamma function (Jacobi sums vs Euler beta function, Gauss multiplication formula vs Hasse–Davenport product relation...). But I haven't seen a Gauss sum equivalent of the relation $\eta(\chi_{s+1}) = s\eta(\chi_s)$. Is there one, and if so what could it be?

Comment: The usual proof of the Gamma function recurrence relation is (of course) via integration by parts; in a real sense, it's a consequence of the relation $x^s=x\cdot x^{s-1}$.  AFAIK there's no corresponding 'parametrized' relation among different Dirichlet characters $\bmod p$, but if there were then you could presumably use a 'summation by parts' approach to derive the corresponding relation...

Comment: The [Gross-Koblitz formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross%E2%80%93Koblitz_formula) expresses Gauss sums in terms of the $p$-adic $\Gamma$-function which has the analog of the functional equation for "usual" $\Gamma$, so in principle something can be said, but...

Comment: @BrunoJoyal Your gamma definition using Gauss sums is amazing:) Could you tell your reference?