# Gamma function and Gauss sums

Tags: number-theory, gamma-function, gauss-sums

In [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_sum) Wikipedia article appears this : "Gauss sums are the analogues for finite fields of the Gamma function."

What was the relation between gamma functions and non-finite fields?

Comment: The Gamma function is defined on the complex numbers, and they form an infinite field.

Comment: A [very good overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXjAK.png) is given in the book by Lemmermeyer, _Reciprocity laws, from Euler to Eisenstein_, p. 139. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523656.

Answer (score 4):

Gauss sums are closely related to an analogue of the complex Gamma function - *the $p$-adic Gamma function*.
Let $p$ be an odd prime. The $p$-adic Gamma function is defined by
$$
\Gamma_p(z)=\lim_{m\to z}(-1)^m\prod_{0<j<m, (p,j)=1}j,
$$
where $m$ approaches $z\in \mathbb{Z}_p$ through positive integers. There is a direct connection between the $p$-adic Gamma function and Gauss sums, see the article of [Gross and Koblitz](http://www.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/otherpapers/gross_koblitz.pdf).